# True Wireless Headphones Lenovo HT10 not working with Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, sound, bluetooth

My Lenovo HT10 True Wireless Headphones work perfectly on windows, but they disconnect in less than 5 seconds on Ubuntu. They have BlueTooth 5.0. Please Help.

Comment: Please provide release details